# Python Plone Passing Data

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

What I want to do is use a form gen form that calls a custom script adapter.
The script will then take the search field and mess with it and plug it into an sql method called sms that searches a mysql database.
All I need to figure out is how to display the results in a page.

here is the script so far

```
  
#  ploneformgen = PloneFormGen object
request = container.REQUEST
form = request.form
RESPONSE = request.RESPONSE
if form.has_key('string-1') and form.has_key('form.submitted'):
    srch=form['search-1'], "%s" %'\%' 
    context.sms(srch)
```

I need the results of context.sms() to be formatted and passed to a page template or somthing.

I used the traverse_to:string: method once to get a custom page template to appear after but I dont know how to pass my own data in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I used the traverse_to:string: method once to get a custom page template to 
appear after but I dont know how to pass my own data in.
```

Inside your template you can call arbitrary scripts (or other callable code like browser views) in general through acquisition. If your code is located inside a script **foo** then
use something like

```
<tal:def define="result context/foo">

  <div tal:content="result/data1" />
  <div tal:content="result/data2" />

</tal:foo>
```

Inside the implementation of the foo script you just have to return the data that you need in the template. Usually you may return a dict e.g. with keys data1 or data2 holding the values to be rendered.

Comment: Do I nee to have a dict called result and a key 'data1'? Do I nee to edit the Response object?